# uk sort code regex with string

Tags: regex

I have a string input with UK sort code. (ex: "My UK Sort code is 873492"). The customer types this and the agent has to respond with a "My UK sort code is ******".

Forum posts here about regex doesn't clearly say how to mask only the UK code and leave the string as it is. Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to extract `873492` from `My UK Sort code is 873492` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [tour]. A minimal effort is appreciated. Try something and [edit] it into your post.

Answer (score 2):

As **sort codes** have 6 digits and they are usually formatted as three pairs of numbers (e.g. `12-34-56`) I would also try to match that, so you would need something like:

```js
var sortcode = document.getElementById("sortcode");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

sortcode.oninput = function(e){
 
  var match = sortcode.value.match(/\d{6}|\d{2}\s*?\-\s*?\d{2}\s*?\-\s*?\d{2}/); 
  
  if(match == null)
    result.innerHTML = "There is no sort code in your input";
  else
    result.innerHTML = sortcode.value.replace(/\d{6}|\d{2}\s*?\-\s*?\d{2}\s*?\-\s*?\d{2}/g, "******")
  
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sortcode" placeholder="Enter a sentence with your sort code"/>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Note it will also match:

- Any formatted sort code even if there are spaces between the digits and the dashes (e.g. `12-      34          -56` will be `******`).
- Numbers with a multiple of 6 number of digits (e.g. `123456789012` will be `************`).
- Any 6 digits number even if it is not space delimited (e.g. `123456789` will be `******789`).

If you don't want that, you can make some assumptions to make this **more restrictive** so that is less probable that you hide something that is not a sort code, but at the same time it will be more probable not to match something that is a sort code but that does not match the extra criteria.

For example, let's say your sort codes are always preceded by a space and are always at the end of the sentence (i.e. they are followed by nothing or by a dot). The code will then be:

```js
var sortcode = document.getElementById("sortcode");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

sortcode.oninput = function(e){
 
  var match = sortcode.value.match(/\s\d{6}\.?$|\s\d{2}\s*?\-\s*?\d{2}\s*?\-\s*?\d{2}\.?$/); 
  
  if(match == null)
    result.innerHTML = "There is no sort code in your input";
  else
    result.innerHTML = sortcode.value.replace(/\s\d{6}\.?$|\s\d{2}\s*?\-\s*?\d{2}\s*?\-\s*?\d{2}\.?$/, " ******")
  
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sortcode" placeholder="Enter a sentence with your sort code"/>

<div id="result"></div>
```